# Bing stopped indexing the site after disallowing all crawlers except Googlebot, Yahoo-slurp, and Msnbot

Tags: robots.txt, bing, bing-webmaster-tools, bingbot

Bing removed my top pages from results, 3 days ago they were showing at first page. Maybe i updated robots.txt file few weeks ago. Can someone check below template if there is something wrong that is blocking bingbot to index my top pages. Thanks in advance

```
User-agent: * 
Crawl-Delay: 20

User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow:

User-agent: Yahoo-slurp
Disallow: 

User-agent: Msnbot
Disallow:
```

Answer (score 3):

Msnbot is just one of the user agents that Bing users, and it isn't even the main one.  According to https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/which-crawlers-does-bing-use-8c184ec0

- **Bingbot** - Main bing crawler
- **Msnbot** - Old crawler, still used some
- **MSNBot-Media** - Image and video crawler
- **AdIdxBot** - Ads crawler
- **BingPreview** - Preview crawler

To allow Bing to index your site you need to allow **Bingbot** at the very least:

```
User-agent: Bingbot
Disallow:
```

You could keep the **Msnbot** section and also add the other Bing user agents.

Your user agent for Yahoo is not correct either.   According to https://help.yahoo.com/kb/learn-submit-website-yahoo-robotstxt-directive-sln2213.html it is just **Slurp** rather than **Yahoo-slurp**.

While you have the main user agent for Googlebot correct, Google many user agents that it crawls with.   You may want to allow crawling for some of their others as well.   Their documentation is here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en

Another problem is that you have two `User-agent: *` sections.   I would say that you should combine them, but the `Crawl-Delay` directive won't be used by anything.  You disallow all crawlers that would use that section.  If you want to specify a crawl delay for Googlebot, Yahoo, or Bing, you need to add the crawl delay into their section.   Once you create a specific section for a bot, it ignores the `*` section completely.  Note that Googlebot doesn't support crawl delays at all.

To do what you want I'd recommend at least the following robots.txt.  You also might want to allow some ads crawlers from Google and Bing.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow:

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:

User-agent: Slurp
Crawl-Delay: 20
Disallow: 

User-agent: MSNBot
Crawl-Delay: 20
Disallow:

User-agent: MSNBot-Media
Crawl-Delay: 20
Disallow:

User-agent: Bingbot
Crawl-Delay: 20
Disallow:
```

Comment: What I understand, according to my robots.txt file I am blocking all search engines with below command. 
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

And after that we are requesting specific search engines. Bing Yahoo and Google to index our site with other related commands.

If above understanding is correct. 
What should be format to get maximum traffic from any where. 
Because according to my analytics, i am getting traffic from different sources 
including duckduckgo.com
Netdeals.com 
Etc etc. i fear i ll loose my traffic from other sources as well. stay blessed

Comment: I would not recommend blocking all robots except specific ones.  As you point out there are many lesser search engines.  Plus a new search engine could come along at any point.

Comment: can you share a template of robots.txt according to my need ? you send me a very good reply + template in first response but now you understand that my need is little different. Sorry for bothering you again and again. stay blessed always

Comment: Just `User-agent: *` then `Disallow:`  works fine to allow all crawling of your site.  Then you could disallow specific bots that you find problematic.